# Which syntax highlighter plugin used at stackoverflow.com? ( syntax highlighter plugin for Razor MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I know some SyntaxHighlighter in jquery plugins such as:

- http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/
- http://qbnz.com/highlighter/
- http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/

...........

But none has to MVC Razor: (

Need the plugin exactly like the style stackoverflow.com applying codes in Razor, like so

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("Create was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<p>
<label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
@Html.TextBox("FirstName")
@Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", "*")
</p>
<p>
<label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
@Html.TextBox("LastName")
@Html.ValidationMessage("LastName", "*") 
</p>
<p>
<label for="gender">Gender:</label>
@Html.RadioButton("gender", "Male", true) Male
@Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female", false) Female
</p>       
<p>
<label for="Password">Password:</label>
@Html.Password("Password")
@Html.ValidationMessage("Password", "*") 
</p>
<p>
<label for="Password">Confirm Password:</label>
@Html.Password("ConfirmPassword") 
@Html.ValidationMessage("ConfirmPassword", "*") 
</p>
<p>
<label for="Profile">Profile:</label>
@Html.TextArea("Profile", new { cols = 60, rows = 10 })
</p>
<p>
@Html.CheckBox("ReceiveNewsletter") 
<label for="termsAndconditions" style="display:inline">I Agree</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</p>
}
```

Someone knows something that does this?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), Stack Exchange uses [Googles Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) so you should probably look into using that as well.

Regarding Raxor MVC specifically - if you look at how the syntax highlighter works, its pretty easy to see how its highlighting your example.

Google Code Prettify looks for a class name on the code container in order to determine how to highlight the code - according to the Meta thread I linked to, StackExchange use the post tags to determine what class name to apply to quoted code blocks, and if it cannot determine it from the tags then it ... uses the default!

Here is how StackExchange marks up your Razor MVC example:

```
<pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
  <code>
    <span class="lit">@Html</span>
    ....
  </code>
</pre>
```

Here is how StackExchange marks up examples in posts with a C# tag:

```
<pre class="lang-cs prettyprint prettyprinted">
  <code>
     <span class="kwd">var</span>
     ...
  </code>
</pre>
```

The difference between the two is that your example uses the default syntax highlighting definition.

Comment: This plugin does not have Code for MVC Razor. : (

Comment: @pegoj updated to explain how Stack Exchange highlights Razor MVC code using that plugin.